Rutas paralelas no funcionan NextJS/Typescript
En mi proyecto tengo la siguiente estructura para la pagina "Home"
pages/
├─ home/
│ ├─ page.tsx
│ ├─ layout.tsx
│ ├─ @converter/
│ ├─ page.tsx

en la pagina @converter tengo esto:
export default function Converter() {
  return <div>Converter page</div>;
}

Y en el Layout tengo esto:
export default function HomeLayou({
  children,
  converter,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode,
  converter: React.ReactNode,
}) {
  return (
    <>
      <div>{children}</div>
      <div>{converter}</div>
    </>
  );
}

El problema que tengo es que solo el contenido de la pagina Home es cargado, pero no el contenido de @converter, por que sucede esto? Quiero implementar las rutas paralelas de Nextjs en mi proyecto

Parece que estas usando pages router, que versión de next js estas usando?
